# Can the AuthPassword be hashed?

Tags: convertapi

I am creating a web site that converts a web page to PDF and download it to the local server.

Can the `AuthPassword` be hashed to kind of encrypt for security reasons?

Answer (score 0):

You can use **token** instead of **secret**. There are two options for getting tokens:

- Request new token from convertapi server
- Generate token by yourself

More about this you can read here: https://www.convertapi.com/doc/auth

If you are concerned about insecure communication between servers you can use HTTPS and it esures that secret is transferred encrypted.